# How to convert firebase timestamp into date and time

Tags: android, datetime, timestamp

I have tried to get date and time from firebase timestamp as follows:

```
 Date date=new Date(timestamp*1000);
 SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 sfd.format(date);
```

but I'm getting results like:

```
:02-02-48450 04:21:54
:06-02-48450 10:09:45
:07-02-48450 00:48:35
```

as you can see the year is not as we live.

So, please help me to fix this.

Comment: what is your value of `timestamp` and why you multiply for?

Comment: timestamp =1466769937914

Comment: Don't multiply by 1000!

Comment: Sorry guys its my fault, it works perfectly now,actually i am new in android.

Comment: You mean _new in Java_. Welcome and good trip.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your timestamp `1466769937914` equals to `2016-06-24 12:05:37 UTC`. The problem is that you are multiplying the `timestamp` by 1000. But your `timestamp` already holds a value in milliseconds not in seconds (this false assumption is most likely the reason you have the multiplication). In result you get `1466769937914000` which converted equals to `48450-02-01 21:51:54 UTC`. So technically speaking all works fine and results you are getting are correct. All you need to fix is your input data and the solution is quite simple - just remove the multiplication:

```
SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sfd.format(new Date(timestamp));
```

Answer (score 17):

### If you are looking to get a Date instance from Timestamp

If you need to get just the `Date` object from Timestamp, the Timestamp instance comes with a `toDate()` method that returns a `Date` instance.

For clarity:

```
Date javaDate = firebaseTimestampObject.toDate()
```

Answer (score 8):

#### The `.toDate()` method should be all you need

You might like the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)

As an added bonus, you might want very highly human readable output

#### Date only options

`.toDate().toDateString()`

`.toDate().toLocaleDateString()`

#### Time only options

`.toDate().toTimeString()`

`.toDate().toLocaleTimeString()`

#### Objects

However, if you are receiving an object you might do something like this

`{JSON.stringify(createdAt.toDate()).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}`

Converting the object into a string then replacing the quotes around the string.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), the types that are available JSON are:

- `String`
- `Long`
- `Double`
- `Boolean`
- `Map<String, Object>`
- `List<Object>`

Quoting another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format), I suggest you use [*JSON date string format*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` instead of epoch timestamp.

Comparing `1335205543511` to `2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z`, you can noticed that:

- *It's human readable but also succinct*
- *It sorts correctly*
- *It includes fractional seconds, which can help re-establish chronology*
- *It conforms to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)*

*ISO 8601 has been well-established internationally for more than a decade and is endorsed by [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), and [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1179/)*

Answer (score 3):

- firebase time is basically combination of seconds and nano seconds
  time={
  seconds:1612974698,
  nanoseconds:786000000
  }

total_miliseconds=(time.seconds+(time.nanoseconds)*0.00000001)*1000. // 1 nanosecond=1e-9 means 0.00000001

new Date(total_miliseconds)

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

String time=dataSnapshot.child("timeStamp").getValue().toString();
            Long t=Long.parseLong(time);

Date myDate = new Date(t*1000);

Result

---

Fri May 11 05:37:58 GMT+06:30

Answer (score 0):

For date, you can use this code :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", calendar).toString();
```

For time :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
String date = DateFormat.format("hh:mm", calendar).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its bit late but easiest way is just:
`(new Date(timestamp.toDate())).toDateString()`

Comment: Isn't it the same as [Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656048/2227743)?

Answer (score 0):

Within the Date() where you put your timestamp add
`.toDate()`

to the timestamp variable as @jasonleonhard said. Maybe just an example

```
new Date(timestamp.toDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Timestamp into Unixseconds

In Kotlin you can do like this:-

```
val time = document.get("date") as Timestamp
 Log.e("time", " ${time.seconds*1000}")
```

Output:-

1713551400000