# Is there a way by which we can extract date and time from timestamp object from firebase firestore in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get date from timestamp object which we further get from Fieldvalue().serverTimestamp() method.
Is that possible in android?

Comment: try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016376/12543430) hope this will solve your issue!

Comment: For sure, it's possible. What have you tried so far? Please respond with @AlexMamo