# Express Swift Date().timeIntervalSince1970 to Firebase Epoch Time

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed different answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50632217/4833705) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016168/how-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-into-date-and-time)

I'm just getting started learning `Cloud Tasks` from [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a). In that blog post Doug says "What I want is for *expirationAtSeconds* to be the time of expiration expressed in *epoch seconds*".

I want the Task to delete the post when that time is set. In my iOS app I create a post that expires at a specific time:

```
let timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

let postDate: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
var expirationDate: Date? = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: +24, to: postDate)
guard let exp = expirationDate else { return }

let expiresAt = exp.timeIntervalSince1970

dict.updateValue(expiresAt, forKey: "expiresAt")
dict.updateValue(timeStamp, forKey: "postDate")
// other values ...

ref.updateChildValues(dict)
```

which gives me a database value like:

```
posts
  some_post_Id
    -"expiresAt": 1632627680.340107
    // other values ...
```

In my cloud function I want the **expiresAt** date which is a `Double` expressed in `Epoch` seconds. I'm not sure if I should use *expDate1*, *expDate2*, *expDate3*, or *expDate4*:

```
exports.onCreatePost = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const post = snapshot.data();

    const expiresAt = snapshot.child("expiresAt").val();
    const expirationDate = expiresAt.valueOf(); // 1632627680.340107

    var expDate1 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(expirationDate * 1000)

    var expDate2 = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(expirationDate * 1000000)

    var expDate3 = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(expirationDate.microsecondsSinceEpoch)

    var expDate4 = expirationDate.toDate()

    const expirationAtSeconds = either expDate1, expDate2, expDate3, or expDate4

    // continue on with the rest of the code ...
});
```

Comment: did you try `expDate1` and the rest? what was wrong with them?

Comment: @Jesper I'm still working on the code from the blog post. I haven't even gotten a chance to run it yet because I'm slowly trying to understand everything else. Javascript isn't native to me and after I read that quote from Doug, I found 4 different answers so I didn't know which to choose from. But based on your question it seems like `expDate1` would be the best choice. I can figure it out from here on using print statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my question none of the above `DateTime` methods worked for me because I kept getting an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'DateTime' of undefined**.

I had to use `new Date(expirationDate * 1000)` and I got the conversion to epoch seconds from [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/)

Code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onCreatePost = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const post = snapshot.data();

    const expiresAt = snapshot.child("expiresAt").val();
    const expirationDate = expiresAt.valueOf(); // 1632627680.340107

    const expDate = new Date(expirationDate * 1000); // <--------Here

    const expirationAtSeconds = expDate.getTime()/1000.0; // <-------- this will be epoch seconds conversion

    console.log("expDate: " + expDate + " | expirationAtSeconds:" + expirationAtSeconds);

    // continue on with the rest of the code ...
});
```