# How can I print these dynamic data in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have these example data:

```
{
    lastName: "dasdasd",
    totalAmount: 400,
    cartItems: [
      {
        color: "Black",
        size: "500",
        quantity: 2,
        cat: "ML",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200
      }
    ],
    orderCreatedAt: { seconds: 1647338693, nanoseconds: 319000000 },
    Address: "France",
    houseNo: "7",
    firstName: "Anna",
  },
```

I wanted to print the first name, last name, houseNo, address, total amount, the cartItems(name and color only), and then the timestamp date of `orderCreatedAt`. I recreated this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/js-pdf-78272j?file=/src/App.js:184-627

```
  const handlePrint = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Order details", 20, 10);
    const columns = [
      "First Name",
      "Last Name",
      "House No.",
      " Address",
      " Cart Items",
      "Total Amount",
      "Order Created At"
    ];
    const rows = [];
    data.map((item) => rows.push(Object.values(item)));

    doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
    doc.save("order.pdf");
  };
```

With these codes, it will print this data. It isn't arranged and then it shows [Object,object]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it shows [Object,Object] is when you do

```
data.map((item) => rows.push(Object.values(item)));
```

You are actually pushing the whole data object without any data transformation, to the `rows` array one by one. So on the `House No.` column, the [Object,Object] actually represents the `cartItems` object, and on the `Address` column the [Object,Object] actually is the value of `orderCreatedAt`.

Now the `columns` that you defined doesn't align with the data object you have, therefore you need to do some data transformation first. I have edited the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/js-pdf-forked-xkfr7o?file=/src/App.js) for your reference.

Also for the `orderCreatedAt` column, I'm guessing you are getting the data from firebase, so you may need to import the Timestamp from the [firebase/firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) package to do the conversion, but people also found out you can convert the Timestamp to Date with this [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069983/18653164).

Hope it helps.