# javascript "date.getFullYear()" is returning 3991

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

In my chat app(using firebase) I used to store time stamps of messages like this

```
msg = {
  // ...
  timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
};
```

When the msg document was retrieved and parsed into javascript date object

```
const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
const year = date.getFullYear();
```

The **getFullYear()** method returns **3991** instead of **2022**

could anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: `timestamp * 1000` might be the issue?

Comment: Yep, why is it being multiplied by 1000?

Comment: What actual value does `serverTimestamp()` deliver?

Comment: Yup, check that `serverTimestamp()` - I'm assuming it's dropping the leading `1` or `16`

Comment: sorry this question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016168/how-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-into-date-and-time)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't know how to deal with date objects i was told that UTC time formats must be multiplied by 1000. But firebase timestamp has an inbuilt method `toDate()` to convert from UTC to local date

Comment: Depends on the value of the timestamp. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters the timestamp should be the number of _milliseconds_ since the UNIX epoch.

Comment: @Harshavardhan—that doesn't seem to be correct. `new Date(new Date(3991, 0)/1000).getFullYear()` returns 1972, not 2022. Conversely, `new Date(Date.now() * 1000).getFullYear()` returns 54594, not 3991.